# How to use pre-populated Realm database ın React Native?

Tags: react-native, realm

We decided to use Realm DB in our React Native project. We have problem with populating data with pre bundled realm. We tried almost all solutions over web. Nothing helped. Any help is appreciated.

What we have don

```
    Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles();
  Realm.open({
    path: './assets/populated.realm',
    schema: [poemRM,topicRM,userDataRM]
  }).then(realm=>console.log("Heyyyyyy"));
```

we also tried :
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/816
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1759

the official documentation is not clear about the subject for React Native. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this?